# Spaceship chess game identification

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I faintly remember the game, I played it as a kid in the early 00s. The game involved a chessboard where at first you could play chess as you normally would. When a piece would take another piece however, both parties would end up in a spaceship battle, top-down like Asteroid and depending on the value of the piece, stronger and/or multiple ships would show up during the battle. The battle with a pawn against a queen was very difficult from what I remember.

The graphics I think, were somewhat beyond pixelart as the early 00s usually did. I remember the board and the environment of the game being quite dark with the pieces being lighter. As far as I remember, the pieces on the board themselves resembled regular chess pieces.

I've tried looking around on search engines but I usually just end up landing on Battle Chess which is very different in my opinion. I'm trying as hard as I can but I can't seem to dig up a story related to the game.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of *[Archon](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Archon)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is *[Battleboard](https://www.uvlist.net/game-106089-Battleboard)* (1998).

Basically chess, except that when you lose a piece, you enter a...

> ...real-time one-on-one space battle with the two pieces in question to
> decide who wins.

Hat tip to Marcel for game footage.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I haven't been able to track down more footage or screenshots of the game above but I'm very sure this is it. Strange that it was such abandonware

Comment: Small update, gameplay footage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAZZKw3REYY

Comment: @Marcel - Cheers for the footage. I've added it into my answer :-)

Comment: Plug that into deep blue.

Comment: Only 7 files though, so not *quite* like chess...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Sure, if you're a chess *purist*...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman What is [chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_variants) anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Battleboard is part of the "Galaxy of Win Games" collection. See https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/have-you-played-battleboard and https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24697 (with a list). It could be that this CD contained the shareware version.

It is offered on eBay and other sites.

Here are two other CDs: https://archive.org/details/mini-games-2001-v4 and https://archive.org/details/popular_mini_games_v2 (and possibly this https://archive.org/details/cdrom-egames-galaxy) which seem to contain Battleboard and can be downloaded.

Perhaps you can give a note, if you find it there.

Comment: Thanks for more information Sebastian, I just uploaded a video with gameplay to compensate for the lack of footage of this game, I can confirm the popular_mini_games_v2 pack works for being able to play the registered version, that's the one you see in the video mentioned in my comment on the approved post.